# What is Responsible Users in Phabricator Differentials?

Tags: phabricator

1. Go to **Differential -> Advanced Search** in Phabricator
2. The first field in the query form is "Responsible Users". What is it for?

I couldn't figure out for which diffs I'm responsible... even if I'm on the reviewers list or a project reviewer of a diff, some of my reviews are not listed when I execute the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it depends on the state of the diff:

- If the change is waiting for review then the reviewer(s) are responsible.
- If someone requested changes then the author is the responsible user.